# Emacs copy pwd of the current buffer to clipboard

Tags: emacs

I have the following function in my `.emacs` file to obtain the path of the current buffer in the mini-buffer:

```
(defun show-file-name ()
  "Show the full path file name in the minibuffer."
  (interactive)
  (message (buffer-file-name)))
(defalias 'pwd 'show-file-name)
```

My question is, how can I modify this function to **also** copy the path to the **clipboard?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(defun show-file-name ()
  "Show the full path file name in the minibuffer."
  (interactive)
  (kill-new (buffer-file-name))
  (message (buffer-file-name)))
```